# ¿Existe una traducción para “lifehack” en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Hay una gran controversia sobre las connotaciones del término *[hacker](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JxlUKkm)* (tanto en inglés como en español) y otros relacionados como *cracker*. Incluso se llegan a hacer las distinciones de [white/black/grey hat hacker](https://www.cybrary.it/0p3n/types-of-hackers/) (entre otras) para resaltar de forma explícita ciertos matices.

`Hack` ha adquirido por tanto las connotaciones de "pirateo" de computadoras, pero el término originalmente se refiere a algo así como un hachazo.

> **Hack**
>
> to cut or sever with repeated irregular or unskillful blows
>
> <sub>[the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hack)</sub>

Y de este sentido de "[To chop or cut down in a rough manner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hack)" ha derivado a otro de "aplicar un truco"

> (transitive, colloquial, by extension) **To apply a trick**, shortcut, skill, or novelty method to something to increase productivity, efficiency or ease.
>
> <sub>[definición de "hack" en wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hack)</sub>

Tal vez por ese sentido de "conseguir hacer algo aunque no sea de la manera más ortodoxa".

Es por ello que se ha acuñado el término "[life hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hack)" para designar a esos `trucos, atajos, habilidades o nuevos métodos que permiten incrementar la productividad y eficiencia en los diversos aspectos de la vida". El término se usa ampliamente, e incluso hay una stack dedicado a ellos: [**Lifehacks beta**](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/).

A estas alturas los anglicismos `hacker` y 'hackeo`están plenamente aceptados y son intraducibles, pero`hack`y`lifehack` no tienen porqué estarlo.

Traducirlo como "*hackeo de la vida*" sería bastante lamentable, pero quizá entendible (y asumible) debido a la amplia aceptación de `hacer` y `hackeo`. Puede ser que nos baste con términos muy simples como "[truco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=apU9FQv)", pero también es posible que cada uno de los términos usados en la definición (trucos, atajos, habilidades y/o métodos) no recoja por sí solo todas las connotaciones de un "**life hack**". Quizá existan modismos que puedan ayudar en la traducción de este término.

En nuestra constante lucha (en el mejor sentido de la palabra) contra los anglicismos, ¿qué podemos usar como mejor traducción de "life hack"?

---

Ejemplos de uso (cortesía del stack de [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com). **Lifehacks** Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people looking to **bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks**.).

- Are there any **lifehacks** to help the touchpad respond like when it was new?
- Are there any **lifehacks** to open push/pull doors while in a wheelchair, unable to walk?
- Are there any **lifehacks** to get rid of creepy crawly insects in the house?
- I am looking for **lifehacks** regarding how to clean oneself without using too much water, and preferably without any special equipment.

Comment: Tengo entendido que la palabra es continua: `lifehack`. Creo que si fuera `life hack` tendría una connotación diferente ;)

Comment: No puedo contestar tu pregunta, pero me gustaría aclarar *hacker*.  Si tu eres un programador que escribe cantidades de código, manejar tanto código tan denso es un poco como abrir brecha en la selva con un machete (*hack your way through the jungle*).  Así que los mejores programadores recibían el nombre de *hacker*.  (También como dices, *hacker* puede ser alguien que busca destruir máquinas con sus maniobras maquiavélicas.)  Si eres un *life hacker*, eres experto en la vida.

Comment: @diego - ¿Nos podrías enseñar un ejemplo de una frase que incluya la palabra, por favor?

Comment: @diego - Gracias por incluir ejemplos de uso.  El último ejemplo es útil para tu pregunta, mientras que los tres primeros no llega al grano, porque "trick"/"truco" lleva el mismo significado.  Es decir, ni en inglés se necesita la palabra "lifehack" en esas frases.  Voy a proponer otro ejemplo que quizás se acerca a lo que querías preguntar: *I wonder if there's a lifehack for surviving talking to Customer Service?*  Bueno, tal vez ese ejemplo tampoco, porque viene siendo lo mismo que "coping mechanism" (que también es difícil de traducir).

Comment: Otro intento.  "Do you want to know my new lifehack for not forgetting to post a letter?"

Answer (score 6):

¿Qué tal "Consejos útiles"? La edición en linea de [Selecciones (Reader's digest)](https://ar.selecciones.com/contenido/s212_consejos-utiles) tiene una sección con ese nombre y por el contenido que tiene se asemeja bastante al significado que se le da a *lifehack*. Títulos de artículos en esta sección:

- [Soluciones fáciles para ventanas sucias](https://ar.selecciones.com/contenido/a4828_soluciones-faciles-para-ventanas-sucias)
- [Seis atajos del teclado para navegar mejor](https://ar.selecciones.com/contenido/a4799_seis-atajos-del-teclado-para-navegar-mejor)
- [Tips para eliminar malos olores](https://ar.selecciones.com/contenido/a4771_tips-para-eliminar-malos-olores)
- [Celular: tres trucos para ahorrar datos y dinero](https://ar.selecciones.com/contenido/a4739_celular-tres-trucos-para-ahorrar-datos-y-dinero)

Comment: Suena bien. Añadiría también: "Trucos útiles".

Comment: Inmediatamente me recordó un programa español que lamentablemente ya no pasan más en los canales de cable de latinoamérica en el que el personaje tenia una sección que se llamaba **[briconsejos](https://www.hogarmania.com/bricolaje/briconsejos.html)** :-) +1

Comment: Por lo menos en México la palabra que más se acerca a *lifehack* en acepción y tono es ***tip***.  Por ejemplo: *Te voy a dar un tip.*  Así mero comienzo cuando quiero darle una sugerencia a mi hijo mayor (22 años) y no quiero que sea una *sugerencia al hijo* -- ahora que ya es adulto -- *I've got a lifehack for you.  A way to keep your wrists warm when riding your bike in cold weather is by cutting up some old socks and using the cuffs as wristwarmers*.

Answer (score 6):

Quizás el significado de *truco* sea más afín al de *hack* que los de *consejo* o *dato* que, a mi juicio, no aluden al método o procedimiento que describe un *lifehack* ni a la pericia o dominio sobre la materia que denota *hacking*.

> **truco**
>
> 1. m. Cada una de las mañas o habilidades que se adquieren en el ejercicio de un arte, oficio o profesión.
> 2. m. Ardid o trampa que se utiliza para el logro de un fin.

Por otra parte, a la hora de delimitar el ámbito al que se ciñen los trucos, creo que *útiles* no es una traducción precisa ya que no es fiel al matiz del "día a día" que representa *life* en *lifehack* y es además redundante, puesto que la utilidad es una cualidad que se le presupone a un truco.

En tus ejemplos, un simple *trucos* podría ser suficiente porque el ámbito se deduce del contexto. Pero en términos generales opino que traducciones como "trucos para el día a día", "trucos para la vida cotidiana" o "trucos cotidianos", sin ser exactas sí expresan los matices principales que simboliza *lifehack*.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que algo que rescata el espíritu travieso, práctico, ingenioso y versátil de los *lifehacks* sería

> **trucos y mañas**

o

> ***mañas, trucos y atajos prácticos***

Ejemplo

> *Estoy buscando alguna **maña**, **truco** o **atajo** práctico para poder asearme sin consumir mucha agua, y sin necesidad de ningún equipamiento especial*.

El diccionario [RAE define maña](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OJCD3oA)  —que se usa generalmente en plural— como "***artificio o astucia***", "***manera o modo de hacer algo***"
Me parece apropiado aquí precisar más en lo que el concepto ***hacking*** representa. Según el mismo Richard Stallman —programador del MIT, figura capital en el siglo XXI por ser artífice del monumental movimiento GNU y de las licencias de software libre, y alguien a quien definieron como *[the last true hacker](https://www.mondo2000.com/2018/01/11/richard-stallman-last-true-hackers-mondo-2000-flashback-1989/)*—
para quien **hacking** significa ***playful cleverness*** [astucia lúdica]
[[image: Richard Stallman y lo que hacking representa]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92DAP.png)

Es interesante que el término ***hack*** sea por lo tanto —en su interpretación esencial— *un atajo, una manera no convencional, creativa e ingeniosa para resolver alguna necesidad*. El agregado de **life***, quizás un poco redundantemente, le otorga una connotación de *menester doméstico o aplicación práctica para cosas cotidianas*.

En Argentina (al menos hasta no hace mucho, antes de la influencia lingústica que el mundo digital provoca en los Millenials y la Generación Z) era muy común usar "*darse maña*" o "*amañarse*" en el sentido que el diccionario también lista, para **resolver algo con habilidad, de manera ingeniosa o poco convencional**).

Agrego un párrafo de uso sobre la superación de dificultades que debe hacer un zurdo (que le requieren **amañarse**)

> ¿cómo sería ir al colegio o universidad y sentarse en un banco para diestros, siendo zurdos? La verdad es una situación caótica, hay que ***amañarse*** para poder encontrar la posición correcta para poder escribir (...) ( https://www.zonenights.com/2018/08/un-mundo-al-reves-la-dura-vida-de-un-zurdo)

Comment: A ver si entendí tu idea.  *Cuando tengo una carta que no quiero olvidar de llevar al correo, me doy una maña para no dejarla olvidada en la casa: la pongo en el piso justo delante de la puerta.  Así, la veo cuando salgo al trabajo por la mañana.*  ¿Así es como se usa?  ¿Nos das otros ejemplos, por favor?

Comment: Algo así,  puede decirse: *"una **truco o maña** para no olvidar la carta que tienes que enviar al correo al día siguiente, es dejarla en el piso antes de la puerta, de manera que ineludiblemente veas al salir"*

Comment: Gracias.  ¿Otros ejemplos de su uso, por favor?

Comment: *"El muchacho en minutos y sin más que con los elements que encontró al alcance, *se dió maña* para reparar la pérdida  y restituir  el mecanismo que parecía irredimiblemente dañado*"

Comment: Bonito pero sería más útil si pudieras construir algo equivalente a *I am looking for lifehacks regarding how to clean oneself without using too much water, and preferably without any special equipment.*.  No tiene que ser una traducción precisa.

Comment: *"El manejo requería mucha fuerza, pero al cabo de un tiempo **le encontró la maña** al gobierno del vehículo y llegó a conducirlo con destreza"*

Comment: Sería algo así como: *"Estoy buscando alguna **maña o truco** para asearme  sin consumir mucha agua, y poder hacerlo {preferentemente), sin necesidad de ningún equipamiento especial"*

Comment: Me gusta *maña* y *amañarse*.

Answer (score 1):

**Trucos/datos útiles** son buenas interpretaciones idiomáticas.